# Zero-dimensional space of size $\mathbb R$ contains a Cantor set?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I wonder if this is true:

> If $X$ is a separable metric space of cardinality $|\mathbb R|$, then $X$ contains a Cantor set.

What if, additionally, $X$ is perfect (no isolated points) and zero-dimensional? (Assume this if it makes the argument easier).

Comment: What is the general definition of a Cantor set?  I can only find definitions as subsets of $\mathbb R$

Comment: I just mean homeomorphic to Cantor set.  There are many different set representations, such as the middle-thirds set in $\mathbb R$, the product $2^\omega$, etc.

Comment: According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_space) "every uncountable, separable, completely metrizable space contains Cantor spaces as subspaces."  Are you just asking whether "completely metrizable" can be weakened to "metric"?

Comment: @saulspatz essentially, but I also will allow perfect and zero-dimensional assumptions

Comment: I suggest you state what is known in your question, so a browser like me can estimate the level of sophistication probably needed to answer the question.  At first, it sounded like a challenging problem I might like to attempt, but if it's sharpening a well-known result, I know it's out of my league.

Comment: If $X$ is uncountable & separable  and if there exists a $complete$ metric on $X$ that generates the topology on $X,$ then $X$ has  closed uncountable subspace $Y$ with no isolated  points,... A non-empty completely metrizable space $Y$ with no isolated points  contains a Cantor set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a partial answer, where we don't impose a dimension hypothesis:

Using the axiom of choice, we can construct a set of reals that - as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology - doesn't contain any Cantor sets. The key point is that *there are only continuum-many closed sets of reals*, and in particular only continuum-many Cantor sets in $\mathbb{R}$, and so we can do a standard diagonalization argument to produce such a set.

In fact, we can do even better: we can construct a [Bernstein set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_set), which is a set of reals which meets every perfect set but contains no perfect set. Note that the complement of a Bernstein set is *also* a Bernstein set. Furthermore, Bernstein sets have to be dense (so no isolated points).

---

Conversely, over ZF the determinacy of the perfect set game - and hence a fortiori the [axiom of determinacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_determinacy) - implies that the answer to your question is **yes** (even without a dimensionality hypothesis).

Comment: Do you have a source/proof  for the last part of your answer?

Comment: @ForeverMozart I don't have a source. Unless I'm missing something, though, the proof is straightforward. If $X$ is a separable metric space, then AD implies that the perfect set game on $X$ (where the open sets played are chosen from some fixed countable base) is determined *(the countable base means that we can represent this game as a game on naturals; now apply AD)*. Now the usual analysis (see e.g. Kechris' book) shows that if player $1$ has a winning strategy then $X$ has a perfect subset, and if player $2$ has a winning strategy then $X$ is countable.

Comment: Specifically, look at the proof of Theorem 21.1 of Kechris' book Classical descriptive set theory. Although "perfect Polish" is used as a hypothesis, it is not needed. The role of separability here, incidentally, is merely to "translate" the perfect set game into a game on $\mathbb{N}$ to which the axiom of determinacy can be applied.

Comment: A Bernstein set is zero-dimensional because it covers no non-empty interval so its complement is dense in $\Bbb R$.